# GIT quotient of an algebraic action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be a connected affine algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $K$ which acts algebraically on  an affine $K$-variety $V:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} V_i$, where $V_i$'s are irreducible $G$-stable  pairwise (disjoint) isomorphic as varieties. If one of the restriction $\pi_i:V_i\rightarrow V_i//G$ of the quotient morphism $\pi:V\rightarrow V//G$ is constant, does that imply any $\pi_j:V_j\rightarrow V_j//G, \forall j\ne i,$ is also constant? ($V//G$ is the GIT quotient of $V$).

It may be a trivial question, but not clear to me and I couldn't find out a counter example ( I believe its not true).

Comment: I had asked this one day back, but deleted for the question was unclear. 

Comment: I think in this case this is fine, but just as a general note: common practise is to *edit* the existing question (button below the tags).

Comment: The question is still unclear.  Right now, I think you're asking "if one $G$-action on an affine variety has a dense orbit, then does any $G$-action on that variety?" which is obviously false (take the trivial action to be the other one).

Comment: @ Ben Webster: You are right, but here I have fixed a $G$ action on $V$ and so on each $V_i\subset V$, the restricted action of $G$. And 
$\pi_i:=\pi|V_i$.